# Excel - célula com caracteres "ocultos"

Tags: microsoft-excel, codificação-de-caracteres

Eu identifiquei esta "anomalia" quando tentei usar o `PROCV` da referência e o Excel me retornou não disponível (`#N/D`).

O que acontece é que há uma célula que aparentemente é "normal", mas quando você faz: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, você vê que na verdade há mais caracteres na célula - nesse caso duas aspas duplas e dois espaços.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema maior não é nem tanto os caracteres ocultos em si, mas sim o fato de que eles são imunes às formulas!

Já tentei arrumar, substituir, mas estas asplas duplas e espaços em branco não somem. Nem `COLAR ESPECIAL > VALORES` em uma nova planilha funciona.

Alguém sabe o que está por trás disso? É alguma formatação especial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá, tenta utilizar a formula **=TIRAR()**

Formula Tirar: Remove do texto todos os caracteres não imprimíveis

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigado